# Android button with image background and text and stateful functionality

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, background-image

I want to create "button" in XML layout (if possible) which has background image based on state (this image is NOT 9-patched) and with text. Which component to use?

My `button_states.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_normal" />
</selector>
```

`my_pressed` and `my_normal` are **NON** 9-patched images.

Now if I use regular button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_states"
    android:text="@string/my_text" />
```

button it is rendered without background image.

How to do "button" with text and stateful "static" backgrounds?

Thx

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is doing it in code. Use `setBackgroundDrawable()` on the (regular) Button to set the desired background. If you use your selector as the provided drawable you should be fine.

**[Edit]** To do this using resources, place your `button_state.xml` in the res\drawable folder in use the following code:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_state);
```

Comment: Thx... I'll try... Is it possible to use setBackgroundDrawable() with selector? If yes, how to?